# radio button - how to check a link and send user to URL

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to find the best way of checking a url based on a radio button selection. On my page, I have at least 5 pairs of radio buttons. Can someone tell me what's the best way of sending the user to the correct url based on their selected radio button?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*[type=radio]").change(function () {
       alert( $(this).attr("value"))
    })
});
```

see more code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mMNUE/1/)

Comment: I think you already do that.  On suggestion move on to use `.on('change')` will be a good one.  Also this can done directly in button click functionality.

Comment: Use `$(this).val()` not `$(this).attr("value")`.

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/mMNUE/3/

Comment: the thing is I want to check url and redirect user when he click button. I can have up to 10 buttons on my page. var checkedURL =$("*[type=radio]":checked').val(); and then $(.'btn').attr('url', checkedURL); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your jsfiddle, your radio button pairs are named in sequential order: the first pair is named `1`, the second pair is named `2`, and so on. You can use this to assign a listener to the buttons in a loop. First, give each button an id that matches the radio button group name, and a class to identify them as a group, as follows:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="1" value="http://www.google.com" checked="checked" id="radio-1">
            <label for="radio-1"><strong>link 1</strong></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="1" value="http://www.bing.com" id="radio-2">
            <label for="radio-2"><strong>link 2</strong></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>
    <button id='button_1' href="#" class="radio-redirect btn btn-primary">GO !</button>
</p>
```

So you'll end up with a bunch of those buttons. Then you need to loop through them and give them a listener:

```
$.each($('.radio-redirect'), function(i, item) {
    var id = $(item).prop('id');
    var idparts = id.split('_'); // idparts[1] is now the number portion of the id
    $(item).click(function() {
        location.href=$('input[name='+idparts[1]+']:checked').val();
    });
});
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUM8u/) where I've replaced the `location.href` assignment with an `alert` call, so that the frame that contains the executing code won't go away. As long as you are consistent with your naming standard, this will work. If you change your radio button names to, say `radiobutton_1` instead of simply `1`, you just modify the `location.href` line to incorporate the full name.

If you are *not* consistent with your naming, then you'll have to manually assign the `click` events to each button, rather than being able to do it in a loop. But it can still be done.

Comment: Thanks DiMono, works great! I did try solution using different naming, but it's pointless wen I have 10 sets of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
       alert( $(this).val() )
    });
});
```

there can only be input's of type=radio, so is much faster selecting it by tagName.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is probably to use `on()` listener - http://jsfiddle.net/mMNUE/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*[type=radio]").on('change', function () {

         alert( $(this).val());

    })
})
```

and use `val();` instead of `attr();`