# Linking webpages using radio button in HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, radio-button

I have three radio buttons. I would like users to select a radio button which will take them to the correct webpages. However, my code is not working when I have attempted it. I am getting used to JavaScript and still learning.

Can anyone help me regarding what should I try to do this?

```
$( function() {
    $( "input" ).checkboxradio();
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(radChanged).trigger('change');
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'radio-1') {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com;
        }
        else{
            window.location = http://www.yahoo.com";
        }
});


<div id = "radioButtonRow">
<div id = "radioButton">
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
 <label for="radio-1">Access google </label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
 <label for="radio-2">access yahoo</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
 <label for="radio-3">Go on Bing</label>
```

Comment: There is a typo here,. You need to close the **"** & open the quotes **"**

Comment: @madalinivascu is right, is there something wrong with the <A> tag?.  If it's the way it looks, the better approach would be to style it using CSS.  Accessibility drops out the window when controls are abused, had this yesterday when someone wanted something disabling, and thought disabling pointer-events was the way to go, when there is a disabled attribute.

Comment: i dont think @madalinivascu is right because i dont want anything to do with styling what i want is to allow users to select a radio button will links to a webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished in HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">
```

Or in jQuery, you can call the onclick function for each radio button like this:

```
$("input[name='radio-1']").click(function(){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com"
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4zsy8nf/1/

Comment: thanks i voted your question because it has worked however do i have to create another input function for the other radio buttons?

Comment: If you do it this way, yes.  There is a way to loop over your radio buttons with a single function and set their click events.  Check out the answer to this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722505/radio-button-how-to-check-a-link-and-send-user-to-url